# Files on the external driver not opening after using the driver on mac

Tags: windows, macos, external-hard-drive

I used to work on windows using my external hard drive. Today I just use it on Mac to move some files. Then I tried to open a file from my external driver using windows laptop but my work is not in the file. There are some symbols that are unreadable with mac os written in the top page of the file..
I tried to rename the driver but got this message 
you'll need to provide administrator permission..

All my work for months is saved on this driver and have no additional copy..

Can anyone help me how I can get my files back..
I’m devastating right now..
I appreciate any help .....

Comment: Connect your external drive to a windows machine, rename your file to a readable character set.

Also, make a backup of your files.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to do that but I got this message: “ you need to provide administrator permission to .. I’m not sure what I do now..